# How to rotate object counterclockwise?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can't find a single answer to this question. I apologize if this is a duplicate post but I can't find anything.

I'm trying to animate an object counterclockwise in a 2D game in Unity. I assume there must be a simple one or two line code to do this, but I can't figure it out. Everything I've read says that rotating clockwise is easy but that Unity makes counter-clockwise rotation more complicated?

Comment: If you can rotate clockwise, then simply negate the angle to rotate counter-clockwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before we get into the coding bits of this question. 
You first need to understand the logic behind what you want to achieve. 
*counter clockwise* is just **the angle you want to rotate** but negated (-).

To rotate in 2D around an object you can simply do:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        // Spin the object around the world origin at 20 degrees/second.
        transform.RotateAround(Vector3.zero, Vector3.up, 20 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

In 2D the Axis of rotation will simply become Vector3.back or Vector3.forward depending on the direction you want to rotate

Example from: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html

And as user “Programmer” pointed out: `transform.Rotate` will do the trick if you’re not looking to rotate the object around another object.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        // Rotate the object around its local X axis at 1 degree per second
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime);

        // ...also rotate around the World's Y axis
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
    }
}
```

Example from: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html

Since OP has clarified even further what he wants to achieve. I'll leave these images for reference:

[image: z = 0]
[image: z = -10]

With that said: try:

```
 Vector3 direction = player.transform.position - iss.transform.position;
 float angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * mathf.Rad2Deg;
 iss.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
```

Comment: OP wants to rotate an object **not** rotate object around another object...`transform.Rotate` is more appropriate here than `transform.RotateAround`

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't clarify this in my original post, but I do know about transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime), but as you said that rotates around the x axis, or y for up. My problem is since it's a 2D program, I need to rotate it along the Z axis. What can I do to rotate it counterclockwise on the Z axis?

Comment: I left two images for reference on how the Z-axis affects the scene in 2D and a solution below the images.

Comment: Sorry I haven't been online in awhile, I marked it solved. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `transform.Rotate()` function you just have to negate the last parameter.
The default rotation is clockwise so negating the value of the clockwise movement will make the rotation counterclockwise.

Example:

```
public float rotationSpeed = 100f;

public void rotateClockwise()
    {
        transform.Rotate(0f, 0f, (rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
    }

public void rotateCtrClockwise()
    {
        transfrom.Rotate(0f, 0f, -(rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
    }
```